# How to customise the Carbon class to calculate age based on months instead years in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using the Carbon class to calculate the age 
but I would like to customize it so that it can calculate age based on months like 20 months.

here my model

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->age;
    }
```

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference, specifically `diffInMonths()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbon has the `diffInMonths` method which returns the difference between 2 dates in months.
You need to calculate the difference from `created_at` date up to `now`.

Here is the code:

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->diffInMonths($now);
}
```

Comment: So what am I gonna use to use the value in the view

Comment: @Jimmyjbk The same thing you were (likely) already using; `{{ $model->age }}`

Comment: the method getAgeAttribute is a Laravel accessor and it is called when you try to access a property age from the model. So supposing you have a `$person` variable you can call it like this: `$person->age`.

Link to Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor